# Can I connect multiple laptop HDDs to my desktop's motherboard?

Tags: hard-drive

I might be getting a desktop with an SSD, but still have 3 or 4 laptop HDDs. Can I simply connect them to the Asus Z170-A ATX LGA1151 motherboard and have them show up as separate drives?

I don't particularly care for RAID configurations. I remember this to be the case in the good old days (10-12 years ago) but haven't dealt with desktops in a while, so better safe than sorry, and if I can save on HDDs and recycle my own, why not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I simply connect them to the Asus Z170-A ATX LGA1151 motherboard

Laptops usually use 2½ inch SATA drives. This uses the same SATA interface as regular desktop drives. So yes, you can simply connect them.

> and have them show up as separate drives?

Yes.

Possible exceptions:

1. If you use a 10 to 15 year old laptop drive, it might still use classic parallel ATA.
2. If you have a very modern laptop, it might use an M.2 disk.

Modern motherboards do typically have M.2 connectors, but a limited number of them. (Often 1 or 2).

> If I can save on HDDS and recycle my own, why not.

If the recycled disks are old and relatively slow, it might not make much sense to use them. E.g. I got a 4TB disk in my desktop and an unused 60GB ex-laptop disk. Power and noise vs this little extra storage means that I did not use the small disk.

This will of course depend a lot on the disks you intend to re-use and how much space you require.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can reuse your old drives on your new system. The only limitation as Mustafa pointed out would be the free SATA ports on your motherboard and the amount of power connections coming from your PSU. In your case with that motherboard you would have a total of 6 SATA ports but you can also add expansion cards which can increase the amount of supported SATA drives. On the OS side you shouldn't meet any limitations.

Mind that you won't be able to run applications nor OSs from those drives but rather only access the current data from the drives so it's recommended to delete the old Boot and system partitions from those drives once you have your system set up properly in order to avoid errors.

Let us know if you need help!

Answer (score 1):

You can connect as many HDDs or SSDs as your mainboard supports. There is no limitation of physical drives in modern systems (apart from number of sockets of course).

Comment: Number of SATA sockets seems to be 6 or 6+2 for this motherboard. Plenty. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on the slots of motherboard. Taking my computer for example (TP E42), it has two slots for external drive. I replaced stock hard drive with a new SSD (increased performance) and insert the old drive on DVD Drive.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need a passive adapter to connect the laptop drives to the desktop, these adapters are cheap. You can find also cases.

But I recommend you to buy a real (and modern) harddisk, and then only one adapter, and copy one drive at a time to the larger harddisk.

Comment: I suspect that you are thinking of adaptors from 44pins laptop **PATA** to 40 pins desktop **PATA**, but non-ancient laptops use SATA which has the same interface for both 3.5 and 2.5 inch disks.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the specs of your motherboard](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/Z170-A/), it supports up to six hard drives (1 hard drive or SSD per SATA connector). It also has an M.2 connector that you might be able to use, depending on your SSD. If you want to connect more hard drives or SSDs, you'll need to get a SATA controller that you can plug into a PCI slot on the motherboard.

Each drive will need a SATA connection to the motherboard for data, and a power connection. Most motherboards include some cables and they are pretty cheap if you need to order more. Depending on how old your laptop drives are, you might need to use an adapter if they use an old connector type.

I would personally recommend purchasing a new hard drive instead of using your old laptop drives. In my experience full-size hard drives are more reliable than laptop drives, and hard drives aren't expensive nowadays. (I got a 6TB WD Black for about €110)

Comment: From your link: `6 x SATA 6Gb/s port(s)` and `1 x M.2 x4`. So depending on the SSD used 6 or 7 drives max without adding extra PCI-e cards or without using port multipliers..

Comment: @Hennes I can't find that 6x anywhere. [this](https://ducohosting.com/screenshots/isaac6b0121de30f0351c2727ffed2e1247e3.png) is what I see.

Comment: @Hennes Oh, nevermind. I see it now.

Comment: They really could have added 1x SATA express or 2x SATA to that picture.